# .htaccess rewrite mode is not working

Tags: .htaccess

rewrite script in .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
```

`RewriteRule ^index/page/(.*)$ index.php?page=$1`

It works in local machine. but in server it does not work. can any body help me?

Answer (score 1):

Have you verified that the rewrite module is loaded on your server?  If the server is running apache you should be able to verify this with

```
apache2ctl -t -D DUMP_MODULES
```

and looking for the rewrite_module in the response.  (NB: You may need *apachectl* depending on the machine you are using.)

If it is not loaded you might need to change your server configuration.  This is doable (again, depending on the version of apache in use) with a step like

```
a2enmod rewrite
```

or ensuring your *httpd.conf* file contains

LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/apache2/mod_rewrite.so

or by ensuring there's a symbolic link between the rewrite.load file */etc/apache2/mods-enabled* and */etc/apache2/mods-available*.

Don't forget to restart apache afterwards.

Comment: its loaded and have already tested it. the server is godaddy.